# Can anyone identify these 4? (Extra 1x3 brick for scale)

Tags: part-identification

[image]

I found these in with my old LEGO while sorting for my daughters, hardly been used in around 30 years, some came from my great granddad. What are these red things without studs for?

Comment: Welcome. Do these items have the LEGO logo marked on them?

Comment: No obvious logo, too well made not to be for something...

Comment: They don't look like LEGO to me.

Answer (score 9):

These are [Part bb300 Garage Door Counterweight - Old without Hinge Pin](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb300&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

from [Part # 822ac02 - Garage Door Solid Assembly - Old (Hinge Pins on Counterweights - Both Sides)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=822ac02&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

which belongs to

[Set #435-2: Garage Plate and Door (The Building Toy)](https://brickset.com/sets/435-2/Garage-Plate-and-Door-(The-Building-Toy))

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now I want to go home & check  the garage doors!

Comment: Awesome, I have a bunch of those plates with the funny ramp in the middle.